# dynamic query laravel eloquent with whereHas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, dynamicquery

I want to create dynamic filters.
for example I want to create this code

```
$Contact = Contact::whereHas('User', function ($query) use ($searchString) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%Jhone%')->orwhere('family', '<>' . 'Doe');
    })->whereHas('Account', function ($query) use ($searchString) {
        $query->where('account_name', '=' , 'test_account' )->orwhere('account_city', 'like', '%test_city%');
    })->get();
```

and all of parameters is variable 
`name`,`like`,`%Jhone%`,`family`,`<>`,`Doe`,.....
and I want to pass variables to function and function create above query.

Comment: What exactly is your current problem? How does the rest of your controller action look like?

Comment: I want to create function and passvaribles to custom function and it can create my query like above query. I don't what to do?

Comment: @paranoid : this is your requirement. please add your try also ?

Comment: @C2486 See  namoshek  answer and I want to pass array like this to getaccounts method `$classes=array(['User'=>['name','like','%Jhone%'],['family','<>','Doe']],['Account'=>['account_name','=','test_account'],['account_city','like','%test_city%']])`

Comment: yes I understand, but I wanted to see your effort ?

Comment: @C2486 Namoshek answers is work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the relationship functions within your `Contact`, `User` and `Account` models are written in `camelCase` and not `PascalCase` like your example shows.

```
public function getContacts(Request $request)
{
    return Contact::when($request->get('username'), function ($query, $val) use ($request) {
            $query->whereHas('user', function ($q) use ($val, $request) {
                $q->where('name', 'like', '%'.$val.'%');
                if ($request->has('familyname')) {
                    $q->orWhere('family', '<>', $request->get('familyname'));
                }
            });
        })
        ->when($request->get('accountname'), function ($query, $val) use ($request) {
            $query->whereHas('account', function ($q) use ($val, $request) {
                $q->where('account_name', $val);
                if ($request->has('city')) {
                    $q->orWhere('account_city', 'like', '%'.$request->get('city').'%');
                }
            });
        })
        ->get();
}
```

This function will return all contacts when no `GET` parameters are given on the request. If a parameter for `username` is present, it will only return contacts where a user with the given name exists for. If furthermore a `familyname` parameter is present, it will give contacts with a user that has a matching username or a familyname different from the one given. The very same applies to the account, accountname and city.

In particular, there are two things interesting about this example:

- The `when($value, $callback)` function can be used to build very dynamic queries which only execute the `$callback` when `$value` is true. If you use `$request->get('something')` and `something` is not available as parameter, the function will return `null` and the callback is not executed. The callback itself has the form `function ($query, $value) { ... }`, where `$value` is the variable you passed to `when()` as first parameter.
- Using `$request->has('something')` inside the query builder functions to dynamically build constraints on the query is an alternative to `when()`. I only added it for the purpose of demonstration - in general I'd recomment sticking to one style.

If you would extend on the example, you could also build highly dynamic queries where not only the variable content like `Doe` for the family name is given as parameters, but also the comparator like `=`, `<>` or `like`. But extending further on this topic is too much for this answer and there are already tutorials about this topic available anyway.

---

**Edit: here an example for a dynamic query with more detailed input**

Expected input (slightly different than your request because yours cannot work):

```
$filters = [
    'user' => [
        ['name','like','%Jhone%'],
        ['family','<>','Doe'],
    ],
    'account' => [
        ['account_name','=','test_account'], 
        ['account_city','like','%test_city%'],
    ]
];
```

And the function:

```
public function getContacts(Request $request, array $filters)
{
    $query = Contact::query();

    foreach ($filters as $key => $constraints) {
        $query->whereHas($key, function ($q) use ($constraints) {
            if (count($constraints) > 0) {
                $q->where($constraints[0][0], $constraints[0][1], $constraints[0][2]);
            }
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($constraints); $i++) {
                $q->orWhere($constraints[$i][0], $constraints[$i][1], $constraints[$i][2]);
            }
        });
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

This will always use `OR` for multiple constraints and not `AND`. Using `AND` and `OR` mixed would require a lot more sophisticated system.

Comment: Can you customize with this array. I want to pass array like this to  getaccounts method         `$classes=array(['User'=>['name','like','%Jhone%'],['family','<>','Doe']],['Account'=>['account_name','=','test_account'],['account_city','like','%test_city%']])`;

Comment: @paranoid I added an example of what you requested. Please be aware that I changed the filter input slightly because yours would not work.

Comment: @Namoshek Thanks too and one question: in your last code example between IF and FOR needed ELSE? Like this:   if (count($constraints) > 0) {..} ELSE {for($i=1..)..}     ?

Comment: No, you want both. The reason we have two different statements is that you need `OR` concatenation. The `if` will add the first where condition (no leading `OR`) while the `for` loop will add the other conditions with `OR` concatenation.